# Nginx routing got cached?

Tags: apache, http, caching, nginx, routes

On my VPS I have two virtual servers for: 1) apache app (blog), 2) main app

Blog (lets call it app1) can be accessed as a subdomain via: **blog**.sitename.com -> app1.
Main app has a language subdomain access as well, so I defined a wildcard access like this:
`*.sitename.com` -> app2.

And by default `sitename.com` resolves to app2.

Everything worked great up until last Thursday or Friday (don't remember the exact day).

The problem is: `blog.sitename.com` started being resolved by `app2` (not by app1), so the end-user landed on app2 page and "blog" was treated as a language.

Also I noticed that this problem didn't occure in some of my browsers (Safari, for example).
I tried clearing the cache and cookies for other browsers and it started working again after that.

Of course I will not be able to explain this to the users of my site, so is there any way to invalidate the cache (or whatever it is) so that everything would start working again?

And yes, I tried setting `sendfile off` in `nginx.conf` file and restarting nginx - didn't work.

```
upstream app2 {
   server unix:/tmp/app2.sock fail_timeout=0; 
}

server {
   server_name blog.sitename.com;

   access_log /var/log/nginx/blog.sitename.com.access.log main;   
   error_log /var/log/nginx/blog.sitename.com.error.log;

   root /var/www/app1; # Wordpress blog

   index index.php;

   location / {
      index index.php;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
      proxy_redirect off;
   }

   location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
      expires max;
      log_not_found off;
   }
}

server {
   server_name sitename.com 123.123.123.123;
   rewrite ^(.*) http://www.sitename.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
   listen 80 default deferred; # for Linux
   listen 443 ssl; # Handle SSL connection

   ssl_certificate /root/ssl/ssl.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /root/ssl/ssl.key;

   client_max_body_size 4G;
   server_name *.sitename.com;  
   root /root/app2/public; 
   keepalive_timeout 10;

   try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;   

   location @app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; # HTTP or HTTPS
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_pass http://app2;
   }  

   # serve static assets
   location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
      gzip_static on;
      expires 1y;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
   }

   error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;

   location = /500.html {
      root /root/app2/public;
   }
}
```

Comment: @AlexeyTen Edited my initial post. 
That is the entire config file content!
And it has been working like this for almost half a year (maybe more). But something happened last week. And how can it be related to browsers cache - I don't really understand

Comment: Probably you go to http**S**://blog.sitename.com?

Comment: Well, there is no HTTPS connection for the blog (app1).

Comment: And that is the reason why request to `https://blogs.sitename.com` ends up in the only server block that listen to https.

Comment: @AlexeyTen - why? And why it was working like that for a long time? And why is it browser-data dependant?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51739/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-dmitri)

Comment: @AlexeyTen 

Hi. Last time in the chat (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51739/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-dmitri) you gave me an advice on how to fix this problem. 

And I forgot to write it down and the chat-room is not accessible anymore. 

Can I ask you to copy that nginx code here somewhere, if that is possible?

Comment: I don't remember what it was. Probably I suggested to create server block for `https://blogs.sitename.com` and redirect to http from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Finally I found the source of all my problems!

Never ever ever ever use **301** redirect if are not 100% sure that it should be that way.

301 redirects get cached on a browser level and there is no way to clear it out. 
Use 302 instead. And only when you are 100% sure that everything is correct - implement 301, as it is beneficial for performance.